# How to determine the Disabled property of a 'Button' in Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

How can i check the property of a button whether it is disabled or not? The below statement is sucessfull for its existence,

```
@browser.frame(:name => 'MainBody').button(:text => 'Submit').exists?
```

.. can someone let me know how should i check the disabled property? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`@browser.frame(:name => 'MainBody').button(:text => 'Submit').enabled?`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this, it seems to be not working, is there any other method. Thank you!1

Comment: because I don't see the `.disabled?` method in the methods list for Watir http://rubydoc.info/gems/watir/frames or watir-webdriver http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-webdriver/master/frames.  Not sure why it worked for you, what version of watir are you using there?

Comment: Try yourself. As you see http://rubydoc.info/github/watir/watir-webdriver/Watir/Button#enabled%3F-instance_method, `#enabled?` just calls `#disabled?` and alter its return value. I know it's not listed. however, there are specs for it - https://github.com/watir/watirspec/blob/master/button_spec.rb#L231

Answer (score 0):

In `watir-webdriver` this can be done by editing the file: `C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\watir-webdriver-0.6.1\lib\watir-webdriver\elements\option.rb` and before the def select, add this:

```
def enabled?
!disabled?
end
```

It worked for me, as watir-webdriver doesn't know about `.enabled`? on options for `select_lists`.